# What are the choice of materials for LOx pumps casing and impellers?

Tags: propulsion, fuel, engine-design, materials, combustion

Given the highly corrosive nature of LOx and the extremely low temperature, what materials are usually used for the LOx pumps?

- Steel, Copper, and many alloy tend to be flammable in liquid Oxygen environment
- Very low temperatures induce brittleness
- LOx is very corrosive

Given these limitations, what materials could act as candidates for the impeller and housing in the pumps pumping LOx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Space Shuttle Main Engine](http://www.tms.org/Superalloys/10.7449/1991/Superalloys_1991_749_760.pdf) a nickel "superalloy" called [INCONEL 718](http://asm.matweb.com/search/SpecificMaterial.asp?bassnum=NINC34) was used.

[image]

> High-Pressure  Oxidizer  Turbopump - The  function  of  the 
>   high-pressure  oxidizer  turbopump  (HPOTP)  is  to  provide  a 
>   high-pressure,  high-volume  flow  of  liquid  oxygen  to  the  main 
>   injector  arid  to  the  preburner  injectors  sufficient  to  ensure 
>   positive  injection  of  oxidizer  at  all  thrust  levels  (Figure 
>   8).  The  HPOTP  is  a  centrifugal  pump  consisting  of  a 
>   double-entry  main  impeller  and  a  smaller,  single-entry  boost 
>   impeller  on  a  common  drive  shaft  and  develops 
>   16.4  x  7  10  W  at  29,000  rpm.  The  low-pressure  oxidizer  pump  delivers  liquid  oxygen  to  the  HPOTP  main  impeller  at  about 
>   2.9  MPa.  The  main  impeller  increases  this  pressure  to  almost  35  MPa  and  most  of  this  flow  is  directed  to  the  MCC 
>   injector.  A  small  portion  of  this  liquid  oxygen  flow  is 
>   diverted  to  the  boost  impeller  which  increases  the  pressure 
>   to  approximately  55  MPa  to  feed  the  prebumers.  **The  main 
>   impeller  is  machined  from  an  alloy  718**  closed-die  forging  and
>   **the  boost  impeller  is  an  alloy  718**  precision  investment 
>   casting.  **The  pump  housing,  also  alloy  718,**  is  a  complex 
>   welded  assembly  composed  of  castings,  forgings,  and  formed 
>   sheet.  All  components  are  in  the  solution-treated  and  aged 
>   condition  subsequent  to  welding.  **Alloy  718  was  selected  for 
>   its high  strength,  compatibility  with  liquid  oxygen,  and  good 
>   toughness  at  the  operating  temperature  of 
>   -179°C.**

Comment: Is Inconel still the choice today for LOx pumps?

Comment: I don't have direct knowledge of pump design on current vehicles, but it is used for a lot of plumbing before and after the pumps.  Inconel 718 and Inconel 620 are very common materials to see in rocket propulsion systems.

Comment: The RS-25 version of the SSME will power the SLS, if it ever flies.

Answer (score 3):

Liquid oxygen is not corrosive in the traditional sense. There is no electrochemical attack.

It can make many materials much easier to ignite. For a fire or explosion to occur, all three parts of the fire triangle must be present. Oxygen is one, fuel is another (metals, plastics, actual propellants) and an ignition source is the third.

An ignition source can be the traditional source, like spark, direct heat, or from particle impact (debris hitting a piece of metal or plastic and imparting enough energy to cause ignition), adiabatic compression (oxygen itself rapidly slowed by closing a valve, turning a corner), or others.

Metals and plastics all will burn to a certain extent depending on pressure, temperature, and chemical composition. Materials can be perfectly acceptable under some conditions and completely unusable under others. The higher the pressure/ temperature the more likely that an ignition event can occur.

In general, materials fabricated from copper are the best but tend to be lower in strength and not tolerant of high temperature. These include brass, copper, monel, toughmet. However, even these will burn in certain conditions, but due to the high thermal conductivity can cool rapidly. They also do not become brittle in cold temperatures. Many of these will not burn until pressures are near 10000 psi.

Nickel based alloys are the next likely material used, if off the shelf materials are being used. They are high in strength but can readily burn above 800 or so psi. Sometimes coatings are used to help with ignition, but Inconel 718, Inconel 625 and others can ignite at pressures less than 1000 psi.

Carbon steel is never used, as it's easily ignited and becomes brittle at these temperatures.

Materials like titanium can ignite even at room temperature and aren't used.

Material like raw aluminum can also ignite at low pressures, 25 psi. But add anodization and aluminum is often used on the low pressure suction side of the pump.

On the high pressure discharge side aluminum is not typically used as risk is too great of an issue.

Many rocket companies develop custom alloys to deal with issues.

Like all things in engineering, there is not just one material that will work, everything is configuration dependent.

Comment: "oxygen itself rapidly slowed by turning a corner". I heared from an accident at a corner of an oxygen line burned through. After that the central oxygen distribution line was never used again. Never open an oxygen valve very fast causing a steep pressure rise.